# len() 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get the length of the column if it is == 1.

**Create Dictionary**

```
 test = {'home': ['PIT', 'MIN', 'CHI', 'DET'], 'away': ['MIN', 'PIT', 'DET', 'CHI'], 'is_home': [1,1,1,1], 'home_win': [1,1,0,0],}
```

**Create DF:**

```
 new_test = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
 new_test # Display DataFrame
```

**DF:**

```
    home    away  is_home   home_win
0   PIT      MIN    1          1
1   MIN      PIT    1          1
2   CHI      DET    1          0
3   DET      CHI    1          0
```

**Shape of DF to a string:**

```
n_matches = new_test.shape[0]
n_matches
# 4
```

**Number of home wins using `new_test.home_win`**

```
n_homewins = len(new_test(new_test.home_win == 1))
```

**Result:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-07ff7d4df92e> in <module>()
----> 1 n_homewins = len(new_test(new_test.home_win == int(1)))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: Change new_test(new_test.home_win == int(1)) to new_test[new_test.home_win == int(1)]

Comment: `new_test[new_test.home_win == 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num_test`is a DataFrame, it is not callable:

```
n_homewins = len(new_test[new_test.home_win == 1])
```

Comment: But then, you don't have to call `len`, you count sum the mask to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your parameters in a parenthesis, that is why it tells you that the DataFrame is not callable. A small change should fix your problems:

```
n_homewins = len(new_test[new_test.home_win == 1])
```

We changed the parenthesis to square brackets for proper slicing.